# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I get following 2 response from 1 API Call

```
1) {
    "id": 200,
    "msg": "Successful",
    "trans_id": "415",
    "info": {
        "id": "41",
        "number": "3889 is already exists"
    }
}

2)
{
     "id": 400,
    "msg": "Bad Request",
    "trans_id": "CLIENTAPI202306050146459",
    "info": [
        "state : value must be a valid string",
        "city : value must be a valid string"
    ]
}
```

Following is my class file

```
public class Output
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string msg { get; set; }
        public string trans_id { get; set; }
        public List<string> info { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i handle above 2 responses from using 1 class file,

i am using following to send response

```
var responseData = httpresponsemessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                strinputjson = responseData.ToString();
                ErrorHandler.LogSteps(strinputjson, "JsonOutput");
                //var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(strinputjson).ToString();
                tResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(strinputjson);
```

i try to run above code it give me following error for response 1

**Error**: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'info.case_id', line 6, position 18.

can anyone help me on this??

Comment: `"info": [ "state :` this is not valid JSON. Valid JSON must have `{}` around objects, which can only contain key-value pairs, and must have `[]` around arrays, which can only contain comma-delimited values, not key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the response JSON structure is different for both cases you mentioned. The first response has an object for the info property, while the second response has an array of strings for the info property.
To handle this you can mark `info` property as `object`.

```
public class Output
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string trans_id { get; set; }
    public object info { get; set; }
}
```

While deserializing the response you have to check the type of `info` property.
below is example

```
tResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Output>(strinputjson);

if (tResponse.info is JArray) // Check if info property is an array
{
    tResponse.info = ((JArray)tResponse.info).ToObject<List<string>>();
}
else if (tResponse.info is JObject) // Check if info property is an object
{
    var infoObject = ((JObject)tResponse.info);
    tResponse.info = new List<string>
    {
        $"{infoObject["id"]} : {infoObject["number"]}"
    };
}
```